# Regex getting dot files except the current and parent dictionaries

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I'm reading the book "How Linux Works".
The author gave the following regular expressions so I can get all dot files except the current and parent directories. (Page 21)

```
.??*
.[^.]*
```

If any dot files exist in the directory the both work. But when no dot files exist only the first one work.

I can't understand them. Can you describe me?

```
$ ls -a
. .. .hiding something

$ ls -a | grep .??*
.hiding

$ ls -a | grep .[^.]*
.hiding

$ mv .hiding hiding

$ ls -a | grep .??*

$ ls -a | grep .[^.]*
.
..
hiding
something
```

Answer (score 2):

The first does not really make sense, does not work for me, and I cannot find any documentation about `??` either.

Regardless, there are two problems with both of these regexes:

1. The `.` here matches any char. In order to match only for a single dot as it is, you have to put a `\` in front of it, like `\.`.
2. The whole expression can match anywhere in the line. You have to assert that the matching starts at the beginning. So start with `^`.

Try: `ls -a | grep '^\.[^.]'`
This means: starting at the beginning of the line, find a single dot. Then any char that is not listed (negation is done by the second `^` here) between the brackets, so not a literal dot.

In brackets you don't have to use `\`, although you can.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. I found the characters in grep .??* work apparently as wildcards because grep ".??*" doesn't work at all.

Comment: @palacsint:
I cannot accept the answer. I even need someone to describe the expressions above.